# Unable to load dynamic library 'C:\php\ext\php_pthreads.dll'

Tags: php, multithreading, php-pthread

I'm trying to have threads in my php code, but I can't get my head around *pthreads* library and every time I run my program I encounter this error:

```
Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'C:\php\ext\php_pthreads.dll' - The specified module could not be found.in Unknown on line 0
```

I followed every step needed:

```
I've added the file pthreadVC2.dll in my "C:\php" folder
I've added the file php_pthreads.dll in my "C:\php\ext"folder
I've modified the file php.ini, enabling the extension: extension=php_pthreads.dll
I've also added pthreadVC2.dll to system32 folder.
```

Here is my *phpinfo()*:

```
PHP Version => 5.6.38
Compiler => MSVC11 (Visual C++ 2012)
Architecture => x64
```

And here is the version of pthreads I used:

```
php_pthreads-2.0.9-5.6-ts-vc11-x64
```

I have read similar topics on the issue, even did try everything step by step according to a video tutorial but nothing works. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I'm not familiar with the extension but the manual is packed with warnings about not being usable in web server environment and requiring ZTS (Zend Thread Safety) enabled. Are you using a command-line build compiled with `--enable-zts`?

Comment: I'm working on Windows.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Installation is quite straightforward, although a little more involved than the [Simple Windows Installation](https://github.com/krakjoe/pthreads#simple-windows-installation) instructions suggest:

1. Download a thread safe version of PHP, e.g. [php-5.6.38-Win32-VC11-x86](https://windows.php.net/downloads/releases/php-5.6.38-Win32-VC11-x86.zip).

   - extract the .ZIP file to your hard drive, e.g. `C:\php`.
2. Download the matching version of pthreads, e.g [php_pthreads-2.0.10-5.6-ts-vc11-x86](https://windows.php.net/downloads/pecl/releases/pthreads/2.0.10/php_pthreads-2.0.10-5.6-ts-vc11-x86.zip).

   - extract `pthreadVC2.dll` into the PHP folder, e.g. `C:\php`.
   - extract `php_pthreads.dll` into the extensions folder, e.g. `C:\php\ext`.
3. In the PHP folder, copy either `php.ini-development` or `php.ini-production` to `php.ini`.
4. Edit `php.ini` and add the line `extension=php_pthreads.dll` at the end of the file.

At this point pthreads should be working. You can verify this by opening a command prompt in the PHP folder and executing `php --ri pthreads`:

[image: Screenshot of result]

Note that the PHP and pthreads versions I referenced above require you to install the [Visual Studio 2012 (VC11) runtime](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/help/2977003/the-latest-supported-visual-c-downloads) to function.

---

***Edit:*** For completeness, I downloaded what seem to be the exact versions of PHP and pthreads you are using (the primary difference being x64):

- [php-5.6.38-Win32-VC11-x64](https://windows.php.net/downloads/releases/php-5.6.38-Win32-VC11-x64.zip)
- [php_pthreads-2.0.9-5.6-ts-vc11-x64](https://windows.php.net/downloads/pecl/releases/pthreads/2.0.9/php_pthreads-2.0.9-5.6-ts-vc11-x64.zip)

Following the steps above I received the same result (except the pthreads version is reported as 2.0.9 of course).

Comment: Does the Zend Thread Safety requirement mentioned in the manual still apply?

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález Yes, according to the [requirements on the GitHub page](https://github.com/krakjoe/pthreads#requirements) and the [PHP manual itself](http://php.net/manual/en/pthreads.requirements.php). (I did write 'a thread safe version of PHP' in point 1.)

Comment: Hmmm... I think the confusing part is the reference to the `--enable-zts` build switch. I was expecting to see it in `phpinfo()` ("Configure Command" section). Is then the information under "Thread Safety" the same as "Zend Thread Safety" (in other words, is there a "Zend" kind of thread safety or it's all the same?)

Comment: In my ignorance I've always assumed that ZTS and TS are one and the same. Since pthreads works, as outlined in my answer, the evidence seems to support that. I typically work on Windows and use the pre-built versions of PHP from php.net. Perhaps it's possible to compile with only one of ZTS or TS if you do it yourself?

Comment: If it works for you with the official binaries then it's clear that my assumption about  "Configure Command" was wrong. Nice and thorough answer!