# PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library, Windows

Tags: php, pthreads, pthreads-win32, php-7.4

I've installed PHP 7.4 on `C:\Program Files\Php74` and it's working but when i try to load an extension, there is such error:

> PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library
>   'php_pthreads.dll' (tried: C:\\php\\ext\\php_pthreads.dll ...

Which `C:\php\` doesn't exists so I added `extension_dir = "C:\Program Files\Php74\ext"` to php.ini and i get same error with just updated path:

> PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'php_pthreads.dll' (tried:
>   C:\\Program Files\\Php74\\ext\\php_pthreads.dll ...

- The `C:\Program Files\Php74\ext\php_pthreads.dll` file exists
- PHP path has been added to windows PATH
- Microsoft Visual C++ 2017, 2015 and 2013 are installed.
- Windows 10 1909 64bit
- Apache 2.4

---

**SOLVED**:

It fixed by details on this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54024356/547185

Comment: Is this your answer ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52536027/unable-to-load-dynamic-library-c-php-ext-php-pthreads-dll

Comment: Does C:\\Program Files\\Php74\\ext\\php_pthreads.dll exist on your system? If not, you are not running the php version with zts support.